# Find the power series solution of the differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

The equation is
\begin{equation}
y''+(\sin x)y'+(\cos x) y=0,
\end{equation}
initial condition is $y(0)=0,y'(0)=1$.

Let $y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$, then $y'=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n+1}(n+1)x^n$ and $y''=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n+2}(n+2)(n+1)x^n$. This equation will become
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n+2}(n+2)(n+1)x^n+\sin x \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n+1}(n+1)x^n+\cos x \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n=0.$$

My idea is to compare the coefficients of each term, But I don't know how to handle these trigonometric functions. Should I  do Taylor expansion for trigonometric functions? But I don't know how to calculate then. Can someone help me? Thank you very much！

Comment: You can simplify a little by integrating once to $y'(x)+\sin(x)y(x)=1$. Is any truncation order given?

Comment: I have edited my question. I still don't know how to deal with the $\sin x$ in your formula. I need to calculate the general term formula.@LutzLehmann

Comment: Power series of $\sin(x)$, maybe?

Comment: I can't think of a way this could be done easier than what you already described, insert the power-Taylor-MacLaurin series and compute the Cauchy product. The actual result will be ugly, as the integrating factor is $e^{-\cos x}$.

Comment: The calculation is very complex...@LutzLehmann

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown by @Lutz Lehmann, integrating once simplifies the differential equation to
$$
y'+(\sin x)y=1, \tag{1}
$$
which can be solved with the method of variation of constants. First solve the homogeneous equation:
$$
y'+(\sin x)y=0 \Rightarrow \frac{dy}{y}=-\sin x \Rightarrow \ln y = \cos x + C
\Rightarrow y(x) = \tilde{C}e^{\cos x}. \tag{2}
$$
Now, to solve the inhomogeneous equation $(1)$, make the substitution
$y(x)=u(x)e^{\cos x}$; this yields
$$
u'e^{\cos x} = 1 \Rightarrow u' = e^{-\cos x} \Rightarrow u(x) = u(0) 
+ \int_0^{x}e^{-\cos t}dt, \tag{3}
$$
hence
$$
y(x) = \left(u(0) + \int_0^{x}e^{-\cos t}dt\right)e^{\cos x}. \tag{4}
$$
Now, use the initial condition $y(0)=0$ to show that $u(0)=0$. The final result is
$$
y(x) = e^{\cos x}\int_0^{x}e^{-\cos t}dt. \tag{5}
$$

---

Remark: I've just realized that the question asks for a *power series* solution to the differential equation... I'll leave my solution just for reference, even though it is not the answer that was asked for.